# Running Terraform in AWS CodeBuild - deploying lambda

Tags: terraform, aws-codebuild

I am trying to deploy a lambda function using Terraform running in AWS CodeBuild. I am able to deploy the lambda zip file from an S3 bucket but not when my buildspec file does the build first because I am doing Terraform apply in the POST BUILD phase - before the zip gets uploaded to S3. Is there a way to do the build and then deploy the zip using Terraform?

Comment: No, unless you deploy some dummy zip first.

Comment: can you share sample buildspec file to repro..

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to upload the zip to s3 first, add the zip location as the filename in terraform. I usually copy all assets into a folder called .assets as part of the build process then add it as the filename in the terraform. Like the below

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
  ....
  filename                       = ".assets/my-module/lambda.zip"
  source_code_hash               = filebase64sha256(".assets/my-module/lambda.zip")
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks user5739042, this works on aws codebuild for building and deploying, but it does not update in place after I make a code change, even though the source_code_hash value is changing. Any idea why?